# Why does my violinplot start at a negative number even though my scale starts at 0?

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

[image: Violin Plot]

Hi everyone, im currently just trying around some different visualisation methods in Kaggle and I stumbled upon the violinplot in seaborn. Even though my data set only contains positive numbers (0-1900ish), the violinplot still starts at -100 and overshoots to 2000? Did i do something wrong, or is this intentional? Thanks in advance!

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,6))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.violinplot(data=visu_train_data, x='Side', y='Num', hue='Transported', split=True)
plt.xlabel('Side')
plt.ylabel('Num')
plt.title('Transported Status by Side and Num')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.violinplot(data=visu_train_data, x='Deck', y='Num', hue='Transported', split=True)
plt.xlabel('Deck')
plt.ylabel('Num')
plt.title('Transported Status by Deck and Num')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

This was my code

[image: Data set info]

As you can see, my Num-Variable has a min-value of 0 and max-value of 1900ish

Answer (score 3):

This is normal, what is shown by a [`violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) is a [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), which extrapolates the data.

If you want to restrict to the existing range pass `cut=0`:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.randint(1, 100, size=100)})

sns.violinplot(df, cut=0)
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to read [the documentation on violinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

> Unlike a box plot, in which all of the plot components correspond to
> actual datapoints, the violin plot features a kernel density
> estimation of the underlying distribution.
>
> This can be an effective and attractive way to show multiple
> distributions of data at once, but keep in mind that the estimation
> procedure is influenced by the sample size, and violins for relatively
> small samples might look misleadingly smooth.